# How to get a list of dictionary values (common for dicts) for each dict

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to have a list containing dict values of each dict, since I'm workin' with a lot of dicts.

I think it could be more clear with a bit of code:

```
###I would like to know how could I do instead of doing that for each list to have###
list_values = [dict_1['key'], dict_2['key'], dict_3['key'], dict_4['key'], dict_5['key']]
```

I expect it to be like
[value1, value2, value3, value4, value5]

since it should be passed to a 
plt.plot() (matplot.pyplot)

PS: Values are Integers.

Answer (score 1):

#### Concept

```py
[value for _ , value in dict_obj.items()]
# or 
[value for key , value in dict_obj.items()]
```

#### Example

In your case, you can use `extend` feature. something like below

```
ans = []
d1 = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2" }
d2 = {"key1":"1", "key2":"2" }
d3 = {"key1":"4", "key2":"3" }
ds = [d1, d2, d3]
for dictionary in ds:
    ans.extend([value for _, value in dictionary.items()])

# output ['value1', 'value2', '1', '2', '4', '3']
```

#### Cleaner code

```py
ans = []
[ans.extend(dictionary.values()) for dictionary in ds]
```